# matching substring in nginx location

Tags: regex, nginx, location

I am using nginx 1.4.3 and trying to match long string or substring in long url like this:

1. Long url without any regexes

   ```
   location ~* /index.php?/english/Kbase/Article/IRS {
               proxy_pass         http://backend;
               proxy_cache        kbase-cache;
               <...>
   }
   ```

   Result: nothing is matched, but such url exists.
2. Long url with regexes

   ```
   location ~* /idx/index.php?/Kbase/branch/Article/\d+.*  {
               proxy_pass         http://backend;
               <....>
   }
   ```

   Result: nothing is matched
3. .

   ```
   location ~* /idx/index.php?/Tickets/Ticket/ListAll/[\d,]*/6/[\d,]*/[\d,]*.*   {
               proxy_pass         http://backend;
               <....>
   }
   ```

   Result: nothing is matched
4. .

   ```
   location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
               root /opt/httpdocs;            
   }
   ```

   Result: works fine.
5. .

   ```
   location / {
               proxy_pass         http://backend;
   }
   ```

   Result: works fine.

Examples 1,2,3: I tried all variations to match at least substring .*Article.*, 
and it doesn't work, even .*IRS doesn't work, but 4th example works fine.

Am I missing something or what? Please advise.

Comment: The `?` means the preceding `p` is optional. Did you mean a literal `?`? You need to escape it (`\?`).

Comment: yes, even if I escape \? it still doesn't match. even simpliest form location ~ .*IRS$ { return 410; } doesn't work. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the $ sign which has to terminate a regular expression.

E.g.

```
location ~* /idx/index.php\?/Kbase/branch/Article/\d+.*  {
```

has to be

```
location ~* /idx/index.php\?/Kbase/branch/Article/\d+.*$  {
```

Comment: No it doesn't, the `$` just means this must match the end of the string. Please read up on regex special symbols such as `^` and `$`